# SAS- Why C is the correct Answer?

Tags: sas, format

```
proc format;
value salfmt.
0 -<50000 = "Less than 50K"
50000 - high = "50K or Greater";
options fmterr nodate pageno=1;
title "C";
proc print data= work.emp noobs;
var fullname salary hiredate;
format 
salary salfmt.
hiredate date9.;
label fullname = "X"
salary = "Y"
hiredate = "Z";
run;
```

Why does the program fail?

- A. The PAGENO option is invalid in the OPTIONS statement.
- B. The RUN statement is missing after the FORMAT procedure.
- C. The format name contains a period in the VALUE statement.
- D. The LABEL option is missing from the PROC PRINT statement.

Comment: Proc format is missing  `Quit` command?

Comment: This appears to be a copy paste sample SAS question.  If you are studying SAS, and need multi-choice questions with answers AND explanations, then try https://sasensei.com (disclaimer - I work on this project)

Answer (score 2):

When creating a format in `proc format`, you give the format a name, i.e. `salfmt` in your example.  To reference this format later, you need to add a period `.` to the end of the format name to tell SAS it's a format.

This period is not necessary, or valid, when creating the format, which is why C is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that `Proc format` is a bit off. The following worked with. (Had to change the dataset for my own, but logic is solid.)

```
proc format;
    value salfmt
    0 -<50000 = "Less than 50K"
    50000 - high = "50K or Greater";
quit;

options fmterr nodate pageno=1;
title "C";

proc print data= in_out noobs;
    var price; 
    format  price salfmt. ;
run;
```

Overall the syntax is a bit different if you want to create strings or not:

```
proc format; 
    value $populated
    0 = '0'
    . = 'missing'
    other ='Not zero';

    value populated 
    0 = '0'
    other ='Not zero';
quit;
```

For more on proc Format check out [SAS documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=p1upn25lbfo6mkn1wncu4dyh9q91.htm)